# Cobra: Providing context to subcommands without using package globals?

Tags: go, command-line, viper-go, cobra

I've written a simple CLI tool using [cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) and [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper). I've recently been refactoring it to avoid package global variables, largely because it turned out to be difficult to test using the layout suggested by e.g. `cobra init`.

Instead of...

```
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
  ...
}

func main() {
  rootCmd.Execute()
}
```

I've got something more like:

```
func NewCmdRoot() *cobra.Command {
  cmd := &cobra.Command{
    ...
  }

  return cmd
}

func main() {
  rootCmd := NewCmdRoot()
  rootCmd.Execute()
}
```

This has actually worked out great, and makes it much easier for tests
to start with a clean set of cli options. I'm running into some
difficulties integrating Viper into the new scheme.  If I only care
about the root command, I can set things up in a `PersistentPreRun`
command, like this:

```
func initConfig(cmd *cobra.Command) {
  config := viper.New()
  rootCmd := cmd.Root()

  config.BindPFlag("my-nifty-option", rootCmd.Flag("my-nifty-option")); err != nil {

  // ...stuff happens here...

  config.ReadInConfig()

  // What happens next?
}

func NewCmdRoot() *cobra.Command {
  cmd := &cobra.Command{
    PersistentPreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
      initConfig(cmd)
    },
  }
```

This sort of works: as long as I'm only interested in config options
that correspond to Cobra command line options, things works as
expected. But what if I want access to the `config` variable itself?

I'm unsure how to expose the `config` variable outside of the
`initConfig` method without turning it into a package global. I'd like
the possibility of instantiating multiple command trees, each with
it's own isolated Viper config object, but I'm unclear where to put
it.

Comment: The discussion in [Cobra issue #563](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/563) seems relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The cobra team did that recently, see https://github.com/spf13/cobra/pull/1551

```golang
func TestFoo(t *testing.T){
    root := &Command{
        Use: "root",
        PreRun: func(cmd *Command, args []string) {
            ctx := context.WithValue(cmd.Context(), key{}, val)
            cmd.SetContext(ctx)
        },
        Run: func(cmd *Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Println(cmd.Context().Value(key{}))
        },
    }
    ctx := context.WithValue(cmd.Context(), "key", "default")
    root.ExecuteContext(ctx)
}
```